# insertion in unordered map in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
class Graph {
    unordered_map<string, list<pair<string, int>>>l;
public:
    void addedge(string x, string y, bool bidir, int wt) {
        l[x].push_back(make_pair(y, wt));
        if (bidir) {
            l[y].push_back(make_pair(x, wt));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Graph g;
    g.addedge("A", "B", true, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

unordered map in c++ dont uses push_back() function for insertion then how this unordered map 'l' is using push_back() function.

Comment: `l[x]` and `l[y]` are of type `list<pair<string, int>>`.

Comment: `l` itself does not have a `push_back` method. What you see in e.g `l[x].push_back` is using `push_back` on a **value** of an **element** in the map, which happens to be a `std::list` that does have a `push_back` method.

Comment: `l[x]` creates a new mapping initializing the value using the default constructor., if none exists yet for `x`, and then returns a reference to the value mapped to `x`.

Comment: Some generic feedback to make your code more readable, give your variables meaning full names (e.g. from i.o 'y' etc), create an Edge struct instead of using std::pair (first/second will become quite meaningless), create a Node type to hold name and an id (identifying nodes by name will become quite slow for larger graphs). Small optimization use emplace_back(name,weight)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the subscript operator on `l`, like in `l[x]`, it returns a reference to the *value* mapped to the *key* `x` (or inserts a default constructed value and returns a reference to that).

In this case, the type of the value is a `std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>` and *that* type has a `push_back` member function.

It's the same as this:

```cpp
std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& listref = l[x];
listref.push_back(make_pair(y, wt));
```